# Определение скорости канала

Tags: сеть, скорость

Может кто знает, какой принцип для определения скорости интернет канала с помощью сервисов, например, 2ip удаленно. Например, есть ip login pass и нужно проверить через сервис 2ip скорость интернета - какой принцип?

Answer (score 2):

Входящий трафик:

1. Засекаем время
2. Скачиваем файл известного размера
3. Смотрим сколько времени заняло

Исходящий трафик:

1. Засекаем время
2. Закачиваем на сервер файл известного размера
3. Смотрим сколько времени заняло

`Скорость = Размер / Время`

P.S.: Быстро накиданный тест исходящей скорости ( бойтесь бана )

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div>
      <div>Исходящая скорость:
        <span id="out">0</span>
        <a href = "javascript: test_out(); false;">Тест</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div style = "display: none;">
      <iframe id = "frame">
      </iframe>
    </div>
  </body>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function test_out(){
      var size = ( 1 * 1024 * 1024 ), //1 Мегабайт
          start = 0,
          interval = 0,
          data = [];

      //Получаем строку в 1 мегабайт
      for ( i = 0; i < size; i++ ) data.push("s");

      var doc = document.getElementById('frame').contentDocument;
      doc.body.innerHTML = '' +
        '<form action = "http://ya.ru" method = "POST">' +
          '<textarea name = "tmp">' +
            data.join('') +
          '</textarea>' +
        '</form>';
      //Засекаем время старта
      start = (new Date()).getTime();
      //Отправляем форму
      doc.forms[0].submit();

      //Раз в 10 мс проверяем что страничка загрузилась
      interval = setInterval( function(){
        //Если страничка загрузилась, то из-за отличий в доменах
        //нам не будет доступен iframe.document
        if ( document.getElementById('frame').contentDocument === undefined ){
          var time = (new Date()).getTime() - start;  //В мс
          var speed = ( size / time ) * 1000;
          document.getElementById('out').innerHTML = Math.ceil( speed ) + ' Байт/Сек';
          clearInterval( interval );
        }
      }, 10);
    }

  </script>
</html>
```

Comment: @timka_s, А какой файл вы будете закачивать на сервер, откуда он берется?

Comment: Как вариант - Отправка формы, где есть `textarea` содержащая текст, размером 1Мб

Comment: Для этого нужно чтоб файл всегда хранился на сервере. А через `2ip.ru` как такое организовать? Вот много чекеров есть, которые чекают скорость через `2ip`. Принцип бы понять обращения.

Comment: Добавил пример измерения скорости исходящего трафика...<br>
Для входящего - нужен сервер

Comment: Спасибо за пример, но вы немного меня не поняли)) Надо не через свой сервер, чтоб проверять, а через сайт 2ip.

Answer (score 0):

1. Зайти удаленно на тачку, открыть браузер и проверить скорость :D
2. Поднять VPN на удаленной тачке, подключатся к VPN и измерять скорость с клиента, использую шлюз VPN. Проверил ОБА способа, работают))

Comment: Спасибо за пример, но вы немного меня не поняли)) Надо не через свой сервер, чтоб проверять, а через сайт `2ip`.